# Expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to Any

Tags: swift, firebase, warnings

I want to update value of type `[String: Any?]` to firebase but I got the warning:

`Expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to Any`

The code like this:

```
let v = [String: Any?]()
ref.child("xxx").updateChildValues(v)
```

I can use a default value to make the warning slience
    ref.child("xxx").updateChildValues(v)

My questions is why [String: Any?] was referred to `Any?` and how to silent this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I think `updateChildValues` requires [String: Any] object as argument. If you want to delete some objects using this method just set NSNull() value for certain keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much into firebase but as the error message suggests you need to unwrap your `Any?` into a `Any`. It doesn't accept any optional values.

```
let v = [String: Any]()
ref.child("xxx").updateChildValues(v)
```

I think the above code should fix the issue.